# ApexChart 100% touches the bar, though I have offsetY as -30

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, apexcharts

Iam using Apexchart, If I gave offset value as -30 , which means above the bar. It works fine, until I have the value of 100%. If I have 100% value, data labels touches the bar.
I don't want the datalabels to touch the bar, it should always be above the bar.

```
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      background: 'transparent',
      toolbar: {
        show: false
      }
    },
    colors: [
      function ({ value }) {
        if (value >= minimumProfilePercentage) {
          return theme.palette.warning.main;
        }
        return theme.palette.info.main;
      }
    ],
    xaxis: {
      categories: ["A","B","C","D","E","F"],
      axisBorder: {
        show: false
      },
    grid: {
      show: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
      bar: {
        columnWidth: '35%',
        dataLabels: {
          orientation: 'horizontal',
          position: 'top'
        }
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      enabled: false
    },
    dataLabels: {
      style: {
        colors: [theme.palette.text.primary]
      },
      formatter(value) {
        return `${value}%`;
      },
      offsetY: -30
    },
    annotations: {
      yaxis: [
        {

          strokeDashArray: 5,

        }
      ]
    }
  };

  const chartSeries = [
    {
      data: [100, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 97]
    }
  ];
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like a bug in ApexChart as there as an issue with the same problem with OffsetX reported in github issues here : https://github.com/apexcharts/apexcharts.js/issues/1102

Report the bug and get the developers to fix it in the next version.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into the same issue. For now I customized the y axis, showing 1 tick more.

In my case:

```
yaxis: {
  tickAmount: 5,
  min: 0,
  max: 100
}
```

[image]